# Regex to extract lines after the last occurence

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have a paragraph like this :

```
            output 123

            Deepak everywhere
            Deepak where are

            output 123

            Ankur Everywhere
            Deepak where are

            last

            Deepak everywhere
            Deepak where are
```

I want to extract after last occurrence of "output 123" to "last" . This is what I expect :

```
            Ankur Everywhere
            Deepak where are

            last
```

I use this RegEx pattern - `(?<=(output))([^\\n]*)last` . But using this, what I get is :

```
            output 123

            Deepak everywhere
            Deepak where are

            output 123

            Ankur Everywhere
            Deepak where are

            last
```

Can anyone help ? I use this tool - http://regexr.com?360ek

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern and extract the first capturing group:

```
output\\b[^\\n]*\\s*((?>[^o\\s]++|\\s++(?!last\\b)|o(?!utput\\b))++)(?=\\s+last\b)
```

details:

```
output\\b[^\\n]*\\s* # the begining (exclude from the final result
                     # but used as an anchor)
(                         # open the capturing group
    (?>                   # open an atomic group (all the possible content)
        [^o\\s]++         # all that is not a "o" or a white character
      |                   # OR
        \\s++(?!last\\b)  # white characters but not followed by "last"
                          # (here the possessive quantifier is needed to forbid
                          # backtracks)
      |                   # OR
        o(?!utput\\b)     # "o" not followed by "utput\b"
    )++                   # repeat the atomic group one or more times
)                         # close the capturing group
(?=\\s+last\b)            # followed by white characters and "last"
```

You can find the content of the capturing group with: `m.group(1)`

Answer (score 1):

This should work

> ((?<=(output 123)))([^\n(?<=1)]*)last

[Tested url text http://regexr.com?360f9](http://regexr.com?360f9)

Comment: Hi Suresh . Thanks . I want output after 123 or any word that follows output . I dont want to hard code 123. For example, if it is "output abc", then I want after abc. if it is "output def", then I want after def. Any case it be, I do not want abc and def included in the result. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the characters you are repeating cannot include `output` or `last`. You can do this with a negative lookahead at each position:

```
(?<=output )\w+((?:(?!output|last)[^])*)last
```

First we make sure to start after an `output` (like you did in your own attempt). Then we match the word that's following (because you don't want it in your captured group). Then comes the interesting part: at every position, we check that there is neither `output` nor `last` with `(?!output|last)`. Then we match an arbitrary character with `[^]`. And then we repeat, until we find `last`. Instead of `[^]` you could also use `[\s\S]` or `.` and the `dotall` option.

[Working demo.](http://regexr.com?360en)

Comment: The 123 is hard coded .. output 123 was just an example . Think of this, if it was "output 123454" OR "output abcdef" then I dnt hw I will edit this Regex you provided .

Comment: @NDeepakPrasath just leave out the `123`. and if you don't want it in the result, match a single word before starting the capturing. will edit the answer

Comment: I do not get it . I want output after 123 or any word that follows output . For example, if it is "output abc", then I want after abc. if it is "output def", then I want after def. Any case it be, I do not want abc and def included in the result. Thanks in advance @m.buettber

Comment: @NDeepakPrasath you cannot exclude it from the result entire. but you'll find your desired output in [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `1`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=output )(?!.*?output )[^\\s]+(.*?last)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
else
    System.out.println("NO Match");
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Ankur Everywhere
Deepak where are

last
```

Comment: The ungreediness has no effect in the lookahead (except maybe for performance, but that depends on the input string).

Comment: Yes that true @m.buettner even `(?<=output)(?!.*output)(.*last)` would work. I am just more used to non-greedy ones.

Comment: The last example would produce the wrong result though if there are multiple `last`s. Also, defaulting to ungreediness is bad practice more often than not ;). There are almost always better (faster) alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, it works. But there is one more requirement there is some word followed by output like - output <command> . Can you go through the edited question pls ?